# Is there a way to limit max RAM usage by Blender?

Tags: memory-management

Since I'm fairly new to Blender, I'm not always aware of its (and my system's) limitations, and I accidentally overload my RAM kind of frequently while experimenting with for example adaptive subdivisions. It would be fine if only the program would crash, but it eats up every bit of my memory and totally crashes my computer to the point that only the reset button helps. Is there any way to limit the RAM usage just so I can open the task manager and close Blender when it crashes, so I don't have to reset my entire computer every time? I have 16 gigs of RAM, by the way, I know it's a bit on the lower side for these kinds of tasks but that's what I have to work with at the moment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do inside blender, but if you are on windows you can check if these software can help you:

- Process Tamer :
  https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/proctamer/
- Process Lasso : https://bitsum.com/